# angular js highlighter filter highlight text and change text also

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

[image]

my highlight filter

```
app.filter('highlightWord', function () {
return function (isSectionData, selectedWord) {
    if (!isSectionData) return '';
    // var items = selectedWord.split(" ");
    var items = selectedWord.trim().replace(/ OR /g, ' ').replace(/ AND /g, ' ').replace(/ - /g, '').replace(/-/g, '').replace(/"/g, '').split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(items[i], "gi");
        if (isSectionData && items[i] != "") {
            isSectionData = isSectionData.replace(pattern, '<span class="highlighted">' + items[i] + '</span>');
        }
    }
    return isSectionData;
};});
```

in this highlighter is working fine
but in some case, it changes my HTML paragraph

like I search for 'MI' word in highlight search world like 'similar' and highlight and change this to 'siMIlar'

Is there any something I need to change for correct my result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes on code

```
app.filter('highlightWord', function () {
    return function (isSectionData, selectedWord) {
        if (!isSectionData) return '';
        // var items = selectedWord.split(" ");
        var items = selectedWord.trim().replace(/ OR /g, ' ').replace(/ AND /g, ' ').replace(/ - /g, '').replace(/-/g, '').replace(/"/g, '').split(' ');
        for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(' (' + items[i] + ')', "ig");
            if (isSectionData && items[i] != "") {
                isSectionData = isSectionData.replace(pattern, function (match) {
                    return ' <span class="highlighted">' + match + '</span> ';
                });
            }
        }
        return isSectionData;
    };
});
```

changes are
 pattern search text with space in RegExp with ig reg expression